# Insert an integer(not its ascii) in Character Array?

Tags: java, c, ascii

Its a pretty old question. I want to insert an integer in a character array.
Eg:

```
int a=10;
char c[100];
```

EDIT: Suppose I have a character array "char c[20];". I want to put numbers in the array.
Like:

```
c[0]='1'; 
c[1]='9'; 
c[2]='x';
```

on printing the output should be '19x';

PS: I don't want ascii equivalent of integers to be inserted in array.

Comment: What do you mean by "10" exactly, then? Unicode 10? (Java and C are pretty different when it comes to character handling.) Oh, and define what you mean by "insert" as well - in Java at least, arrays can't have their size changed after creation, so you'd have to overwrite existing elements. Basically, you need to make your question a lot clearer.

Comment: Yeah. It will convert 10 to its ascii equivalent. I want '10' to be inserted

Comment: Do you mean you *do* want an ASCII representation of the string "10"? Again, it's still unclear...

Comment: what is ascii value of `C` (character)?? I think OP wants to store ascii value of character `C`

Comment: The problem is that `I want '10' to be inserted` could mean many things and has a very different implementation in Java and C.

Comment: Now the answer is in the question, isn't it?

Comment: You question seems contradictory. On a system that uses ASCII, `c[0]='1';` places the ASCII code that maps to the symbol 1 (arabic numeral) into the first position of the array `c`. For clarification, is the the behaviour that you want or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java you can use a StringBuilder as your character array

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(10); // add "10" as text.
```

If you want just a string with the number you can use

```
String c = Integer.toString(10);
```

or

```
String c = "" + 10;
```

e.g.

```
String c = "before " + a + " after";
```

Answer (score 0):

In C:

`sprintf` and `itoa` are good functions:

```
{
    myint = 10;
    char ary[20];
    sprintf(ary, "%d", myint);
}
```

To avoid buffer overflows, you are strongly advised to use `snprintf`, but `sprintf` is shown for simplicity.

Alternately:

```
{
    myint = 10;
    char ary[20] = {0};
    itoa(ary, myint, 10);
}
```

Comment: you should be extremely careful with it in order not to get a bufferoverflow. This example is safe, since there are less then 20 chars in an integer.

Comment: But it will overwrite any character already present in the char array.